# cordova- window.open() is not working even after adding inappbrowser pugin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I am developing a hybrid mobile application using `cordova`. When I click a button I need to open a url in the website. To this end I am using `window.open` which is working fine in browser but is not working in the mobile application even after adding the `inappbrowser` plugin.

Below I provide the code I am running:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="myButton">Get Free Trial</button>`
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function () {
         window.open("https://indirect-tax.com",'_system');
};
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
}
```

Comment: what does it do? do you have an error at one step or another?

Comment: i dnt have any error... in mobile device if i  click on the button it is not taking me to the url. button click is not responding @Kaddath

Comment: are you using a software to debug your app? if there is an error, it should be in the logs, you can try to add several `console.log();` to ensure some parts of the code run well. (for example, in my case, i launch the apk from eclipse, where i can see the logs, but it can be android studio.. etc)

Comment: @Kaddath there is no errors in my console.. how do we redirect a link from an app to browser in cordova ?

Comment: hmm then i don't understand, there should be something, at least an error if it does nothing.. see my answer for your redirection question. This worked without redefining `window.open`, and it uses same things than you, maybe is it the `encodeURI` that you're missing?

Answer (score 0):

our directive solution to globally redirect `a` tags, we used same plugin than you, without redefining `window.open`. You can modify it to add you rules, this version redirects only links with `href` beginning with "http", and also evaluates the code that would eventually be placed in `ngClick` attributes (you should remove that for safety, it was a test version).

```
angular
    .module('yourModule') 
    .directive('a', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
              if ( !attrs.href ){
                return;
              }
              var url = attrs.href;
              if ( url.lastIndexOf('http',0) === 0 ){
                element.on('click',function(e){
                  e.preventDefault();
                  if(attrs.ngClick){
                      scope.$eval(attrs.ngClick);
                  }
                  window.open(encodeURI(url), '_system');
                });
              };
            }
        };
    });
```